# Can www-data control root files on Ubuntu web servers?

Tags: root, webserver, ownership

I have read about a bazillion posts about how to set up web server ownership, directory, and file permissions.

I have heard use root. Don't use root, use www-data. Don't use that, use a different user for each website. Yada, yada, yada.

I decided to use root instead of www-data. I know the risks. I limit them by only allowing shell access from my IP and I have a password that would take a long time to break. I do more things but that isn't the question here.

I want to show you my present tree structure. All of my hosted domains use a similar format. I'll ask a question in just a moment, but take a look:

```
├── [drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data]  www.website.com
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x root     root    ]  css
│   │   ├── [drwxr-xr-x root     root    ]  font
```

Everything under the domain is at root ownership. What puzzles me is the www-data ownership of the folder.

Questions:
Can the domain line permissions allow someone to override the root ownership of files below that line?
Should the domain line be set to root root?

Comment: No idea where you've read advice suggesting you run your webserver as root, but it's not a good idea. If the website hosts any dynamic content rather than only static html files there will be a risk a hacker can hijack your whole server. It might possibly be that the advice telling you to run each website as it's own user tells you to run the main process as root so it can switch user before serving content. But it's really not a good idea to serve content as root.

Comment: "I have read about a bazillion posts" - sadly you have not understood any of them. Filesystem permissions are TOOLS for implementing a policy or design - along with other components (users, groups, processes). You don't decide HOW to use the tools until you know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ...and no, you don't know the risks.

Answer (score 3):

> Don't use `root`, use `www-data`.

This is the right thing to do. Having public webpages owned by the privileged user is dangerous.

> Don't use that, use a different user for each website.

Never heard of that advice.

> I limit them by only allowing shell access from my IP

This won't help if an attacker is able to pop a shell (which will have unlimited access, due to `root` ownership) from your web content.

> and I have a password that would take a long time to break.

Same. That won't help at all. Besides, you should disable root shell access entirely and set up pubkey authentication for an unprivileged user, from which you then sudo `root`.

> Can the domain line permissions allow someone to override the `root` ownership of files below that line?

You should define "override", but it's irrelevant since the domain directory and all subdirs have read and execute permissions for "others", so any user can navigate these directories.

> Should the domain line be set to `root` `root`?

No, and it would be better to set ownership of all other files under the webroot to `www-data` i.e. the default unprivileged user for webserver content.

Comment: "Having public webpages owned by the privileged user is dangerous" - no, that's absolutely wrong.   Running the web server daemon (apache, nginx, whatever) as root would be dangerous, as would allowing the web server write access to all of its files.  The **safe** way to run a web server IS to have its files and dirs owned by root (or some other UID) except for those files/directories that it actually **needs** write access to.  This is especially true for a site running PHP or some other web scripting language - write access to the site's files means write access to the scripts it runs.

Comment: actually web server daemons are typically started as root (necessary because they need root to bind to port 80, which is a privileged port) but they drop root privs immediately and change to www-data.

Comment: So, the web server should be running as www-data, the files and dirs should be owned by root (or by some other user) and www-data should NOT have write access to most (if not all) of the web-site's files/dirs.  It should have read access to files, and read+execute access for directories and (depending on the type of script and how the server is configured to execute them) maybe read+execute for the script files that it needs to run.